# Name that place!

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

An easy puzzle, but I hope it brings some fun (especially if you are a programmer).

What's the name of the place?

[image: Name that place]

Comment: This puzzle was too easy. I'd recommend trying to obfuscate a little more in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like

> The lyrics to Hotel California

```
location = { "highway": True, "dark": True, "desert": True }
```

> On a dark desert highway

```
rooms = sys.maxsize
```

> plenty of room

```
availability = any(range(0, 365))
```

> any time of year

```
def __enter__(doorway):  
playsound("mission_bell")
```

> There she stood in the doorway, I heard the mission bell

```
assert this == "heaven" or this == "hell"
```

> this could be heaven or this could be hell

```
candle_lit = True  
show_way()
```

> Then she lit up a candle and she showed me the way

```
pyttsx.init().say("welcome lovely face")
```

> Welcome to the Hotel California... such a lovely face

```
#target = os.system("open /Applications/WineStaging.app")  
#no such spirit since nineteen sixty-nine
```

> Please bring me my wine... we haven't had that spirit here since nineteen sixty-nine

```
def feast(masters_chamber):  
return "immortal beast"
```

> in the master's chambers, they gathered for the feast... can't kill the beast

```
def __exit__(self):  
checkout()  
while True:  
stay()
```

> you can check out any time you like, but you can never leave

Comment: That's right. You got it!

Answer (score -1):

> Hotel California.
>   No need to decode your quizz, i realize from the 'mission bell' xD

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please use spoilers to hide your answers. Also, your answer duplicates an already accepted answer which makes it likely to get down-votes.

Comment: sr, first time join in this game